# Swift NSArray subscript a value of type AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

This my my NSArray

```
var RidesData:NSArray = []
```

It is used to store an JSON Array i have converted

```
RidesData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSArray
```

Sample of the Array

```
Optional((
    {
    ContentType = USSShow;
    Name = "Lake Hollywood Spectacular\U00ae (Seasonal Show)";
    NextShowTime = "8:00pm";
    NextTimeSlot = "";
    QueueTime = "";
    TimeSlot = "";
},
```

I am trying to get the Name value using this code

```
let RideName = RidesData[indexPath.section]["Data"][indexPath.row]["Name"]
cell.textLabel!.text = RideName
```

However i am getting this error

`Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?!' with an index type of 'int'`

From what  i have searched, i believe that i am unable to subscript because it is an optional but when i tried to unwrap it with `!` it gives me this error

`Operand of postfix "!" should have optional type; type is 'NSArray'`

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: In the returned array where is the dictionary with key "Data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
let RideName = RidesData[indexPath.section]["Data"]??[indexPath.row]?["Name"] as? String
```

Since `RidesData[indexPath.section]["Data"]` is `AnyObject?!` you have to unwrap it **twice**.

Why `AnyObject?!` ? Because `RidesData[indexPath.section]` is `AnyObject`, and `AnyObject` may or may not have `subscript`. So, the first `?` means, "If it has `subscript`", and the second means "If `subscript` returns non `nil`".

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
let RideName = RidesData[indexPath.section]["Data"][indexPath.row]["Name"]
```

with this

```
let RideName = RidesData[indexPath.section]["Data"][indexPath.row]["Name"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is with the cast**, the array `RidesData` is an optional array: `[AnyObject]?.`

So you must write it like this:-

```
let RideName = RidesData[indexPath.section]["Data"][indexPath.row]["Name"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

`RidesData[indexPath.section]["Data"]` is of type `AnyObject?!` and then you try to access the `indexPath.row` element. You need to first unwrap this part.

Try this:

```
let RideName = RidesData[indexPath.section]["Data"]?[indexPath.row]["Name"]
```